I am trying to use Arabtex with class arabart, arabrepo, arabbook but output is not correct
For purposes of testing, I am using Arabtex with class arabart, arabreo and arabbook to produce full Arabic documents. I know other methods like Arabi and polyglossia but, as I said, for testing, I'm using Arabtex.
Now arabart style works very fine for articles.
The problem is with arabreo and arabbook  for reports and books  in producing chapters correctly.
Here is my example,
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{arabrep}
%\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{utf8}

% gemetry
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,a4paper,tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm,headheight=12pt,headsep=20pt,footskip=30pt}

%%%%%%%%%%%%% document
\begin{document}
\setarab     
\fullvocalize
\arabtrue   
\setcode{utf8}

\title{Arab\TeX\  \<استخدام عرب تك>}
\author{\<الدسوقي المتولي الخولي>}
\date{}
\maketitle

\begin {arabtext}

\tableofcontents

\part {العنوان}

هذا يمثل جزء

\chapter{مقدمة}

هذه مبادئ ومقدمة

\section{نظرية}

- نظرية مورفي الأولى : إذا أمكن لشيء أن يتعطل فسوف يتعطل

\subsection{ عنوان فرعي}

فقرة  فرعية


\end {arabtext}

\end{document}

Now the problem is like this -- in chapter name:

Here are the error messages,

So, my question: How to make things work right?

this is my original code
%!TeX program = pdflatex
%!TEX encoding =utf8
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{arabrep}

\usepackage{utf8}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%%%%%%%%%%%%% document

    \title{Arab\TeX\  \<استخدام عرب تك>}
    \author{\<الدسوقي المتولي الخولي>}
    \date{}


\begin{document}

    \setcode{utf8}

    \maketitle


    \begin{arabtext}
    
        \tableofcontents

        \chapter{بداية}

        \section{مقدمة}

        - نظرية مورفي الأولى : إذا أمكن لشيء أن يتعطل فسوف يتعطل\footnote{\RL{هذه ملحوظة}}

        \subsection{فرعي}

        مرحلة فرعية


    \textbf{تعدد نقطي}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item المبادئ

        \item الأسس

        \item القواعد
    \end{itemize}

    \textbf{تعدد رقمي}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item الأول

        \item الثاني

        \item الثالث
    \end{enumerate}

    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth]{XdWGT.png}
        \caption{الأسد}
        \label{fig:enter-label}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{table}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            %\begin{RL}
            \RL{البرمجة} & \RL{المعالجة} &  &  \\
            \hline
            \hline
                         &               &  &  \\
                         &               &  &  \\
                         &               &  &  \\
            \hline
            %   \end{RL}
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{البيانات}
        \label{tab:my_label}
    \end{table}

    \end {arabtext}
\end{document}

which make so many mistakes,

and  output




now  I write this sty file
%names
\def\partname       {جُزْءٌ}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@chapapp}{الْفَصْلُ}
\makeatother

\def\abstractname{\RL{اَلمُلخّصُ}}

\renewcommand{\figurename}{\RL{صُورَةٌ}}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{\RL{جَدْوَلٌ}}

%arabic numbers for footnote
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\RL{\arabic{footnote}}}

% move number to righrt of footnote and right to left footnote
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{% modify the style of footnotetext
  \raggedleft\noindent  #1
  \makebox[1em][r]{
    \@makefnmark
  }
}
\makeatother

add to my tex file
which make a correct output


no latex errors now 

arabtex was impressive method or using arabic with classic tex, but now it really makes more sense to use modern opentype arabic fonts and use luatex or xetex.

I know, but as I said "for testing purpose "

After trying and tracking what cause that issue,
I found that ArabTeX arabart , arabreo , arabbook, relay on style that assumes you write Arabic in arabic encoding

Which is reasonable for non Arab speakers/writer,
But for native Arabic speakers/writer, we use regular Arabic alphabets using any encoding method -- for example utf8 --
So I have to rewrite all Latex environments in utf8 or whatever encoding I'll use,
for example to correct chapter name
\makeatletter
  \renewcommand{\@chapapp}{الْفَصْلُ}
\makeatother

this solve my error an produce correct output

I'll try to make a utf8 style that produce correct output
including for now abstractname tablename, figurename , etc.
